# Using a footnote in the full name of an acronym

Tags: footnotes, glossaries, acronyms

I would like to use a footnote in the full name of an acronym. Here is the minimal (not) working example:

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{acronym} 
\usepackage{footnote}
\begin{document} 
    \begin{acronym}[ABC] 
        \acro{ABC}{Alphabet\footnote{this does not work}}
    \end{acronym} 
    The \ac{ABC}\footnote{this works}.
\end{document}
```

I'm already using the acronym package to link acronyms with publications:

```
\acro{ABC}{Alphabet\cite{publication2013abc}}
```

But sometimes there is either no publication or a web site is more appropriate:

```
\acro{ABC}{Alphabet\footnote{\url{http://website-for-abc.example.org}}}
```

Any hints?

---

**Edit:**
Based on the feedback blow, this is another working minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{mycount}
\newcounter{savefoot}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\acrofoot[3]{%
  \acro{#1}{#2\protect\footnote{#3}\setcounter{mycount}{\value{footnote}}}%
}
\let\acorig\ac
\renewcommand\ac[1]{%
  \begingroup%
  \setcounter{savefoot}{\value{footnote}}%
  \setcounter{footnote}{\value{mycount}}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{}%
  \acorig{#1}%
  \setcounter{footnote}{\value{savefoot}}%
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \begin{acronym}[ABC]
        \acrofoot{ABC}{Alphabet}{\url{http://abc.example.org}}
        \acro{XYZ}{The End}
        \acrofoot{Foo}{Bar}{\url{http://foo.example.org}}
    \end{acronym}
    The \ac{ABC}\footnote{this works}. Also see \ac{XYZ} and \ac{Foo}.
\end{document}
```

**Issue:** As you can see in the following picture, the footnote numbering is wrong.
[image: Foo]

Best regards, Alex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! `\protect\footnote` might work, `\footnote` is not robust. By the way: this would work out of the box with the [`acro`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) package (which also has a built-in mechanism to associate citations with acronyms by the way)

Comment: @Alex I copy you code and run the case with \protect right before \footnote{this does not work} and I get 3 footnotes on the bottom of that page. Is this what you seek?

Comment: @Jesse: that's to be expected: once in the list, the second time when the acronym is used the first time and the third is the explicit `\footnote` in the text

Comment: @cgnieder Thanks. Also \protect works. But produces multiple footnotes for the same acronym.

Comment: @Jesse It's a good starting point but indeed not what I'm heading to.

Comment: @cgnieder The `acro` package might be an option, but I've so many acronyms already - I don't want to edit all of them.

Comment: @Alex `\protect` does not produce any footnotes! It just prevents the `\footnote` macro to be expanded too soon. The multiple footnotes will also occur with `acro` if the footnote is part of the long form of the acronym. `acro` v1.4 allows to specify different entries for the long form and the list entry, though.

Comment: @Alex see the addendum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind to create a new command `\acfoot` and use it instead of `\ac` in these cases, here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{acronym}
%\usepackage{footnote}

\newcounter{mycount}
\newcounter{savefoot}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\acfoot[1]{%
  \begingroup%
  \setcounter{savefoot}{\value{footnote}}%
  \setcounter{footnote}{\value{mycount}}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{}%
  \ac{#1}%
  \setcounter{footnote}{\value{savefoot}}%
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{acronym}[ABC]
        \acro{ABC}{Alphabet\protect\footnote{this works}\setcounter{mycount}{\value{footnote}}}
    \end{acronym}
    The \acfoot{ABC}\footnote{this works, too}.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Note that you can also define a new command `\acrofoot`

```
\newcommand\acrofoot[3]{%
  \acro{#1}{#2\protect\footnote{#3}\setcounter{mycount}{\value{footnote}}}%
}
```

and use it instead of `\acro` giving the footnote text as the third argument:

```
\acrofoot{ABC}{Alphabet}{this works}
```

---

### Addendum

This solution works better, but has its limitations (for example you can't use numbers in acronym definitions):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newcounter{savefoot}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\acfoot[1]{%
  \begingroup%
  \setcounter{savefoot}{\value{footnote}}%
  \setcounter{footnote}{\value{#1count}}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{}%
  \ac{#1}%
  \setcounter{footnote}{\value{savefoot}}%
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\acrofoot[3]{%
  \newcounter{#1count}\acro{#1}{#2\protect\footnote{#3}\setcounter{#1count}{\value{footnote}}}%
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{acronym}[ABC]
        \acrofoot{ABC}{Alphabet}{\url{http://abc.example.org}}
        \acro{XYZ}{The End}
        \acrofoot{Foo}{Bar}{\url{http://foo.example.org}}
    \end{acronym}

    The \acfoot{ABC}\footnote{this works}. Also see \ac{XYZ} and \acfoot{Foo}.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The trick is to define a new counter for each `\acrofoot` and use that one for numbering footnotes.

Comment: Good starting point. I updated my question and stated my issue with this solution up there.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Looks good. Unfortunately, I don't really want to know whether I've to use `ac` or `acfoot` while writing. So at the end, my goal was to use footnotes in acronyms that do not repeat all the time. I started to play around with the `cleverref` package a bit - but and at the end I might decide to use normal references again.